# Existence of continuous function on $[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Does there exist any continuous function $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow [0, \infty)$ such that $\int_{0}^{1} x^{n}f(x) dx=1$ for all $n.$ Can it be solve by Weierstrass theorem. Any help.

Comment: What do you know about $n$?

Comment: Your question is not clear. It can mean: A) "Given any $n$, is there some $f$ such that...?" or B) "Is there any $f$ such that for any $n$...?"

Comment: The answer depends heavily on how $n$ is quantified.

Comment: @5xum The question contains the answer, so it is $\forall n$.

Comment: yes it is a mistake. it is for all $n.$

Answer (score 7):

I suppose that it should read: $\int_{0}^{1} x^{n}f(x) dx=1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$

Assume that such a function $f$ exists. By Cauchy-Schwarz

$1  \le (\int_{0}^{1} x^{2n}dx)^{1/2}(\int_{0}^{1} f(x)^2dx)^{1/2}$.

This gives $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)^2dx \ge 2n+1$ for all $n$, a contradiction.

Comment: This is more powerful than the Weierstrass theorem argument, because it works with any infinite subset of ${\mathbb N}$ instead of ${\mathbb N}$. It also works with $L^2$ functions instead of just continuous functions.

Comment: We could also argue $|\int_0^1x^nf(x)\,dx| \le M\int_0^1x^n\,dx= M/(n+1) \to 0.$ (Here $M= \sup_{[0,1]}|f|.$)

Answer (score 4):

You already have a very good answer to the question, but I want to address the "can it be solved with Weierstrass theorem" part. The answer is **YES**. First note that for any polynomial $P(x) = \sum_\limits{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ one has

$$\int_0^1 P(x)f(x) d x = \sum_\limits{k=0}^n a_k \int_0^1 x^k f(x) d x
= \sum_\limits{k=0}^n a_k = P(1)$$

Thanks to Weierstrass' theorem, take a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ that
converges uniformly to $(1-x)f(x)$, then

$$\int_0^1 (1-x)f^2(x) d x = \lim_\limits{n}\int_0^1 P_n(x)f(x) d x
= \lim_\limits{n} P_n(1) = (1-1)f(1) = 0$$

Hence $(1-x)f^2(x)$ is a non negative continuous function with vanishing integral, and this implies $\forall x\in[0,1], (1-x)f(x)=0$, hence $f=0$. This contradicts the hypothesis $\int_0^1 f(x) d x = 1$.